How to rewrite a DataFrame-based grouped rolling aggregation function to use Polars Expressions?
I need to apply a custom grouped rolling aggregation function to every nth row for specific columns of a DataFrame. My current implementation works with a DataFrame as an argument and returns the modified DataFrame.
I have a few issues with the current approach:

The function requires specifying many column names.
Irrelevant columns (if present) are processed, even though they aren't needed.

I would like to rewrite this function so that it works with expressions as arguments and also returns the result as an expression. I'm not sure if this approach is more efficient, but it seems like it would make the handling cleaner.
Unfortunately, I’m having trouble figuring out how to implement this with Polars expressions.
Can anyone guide me on how to convert this DataFrame-based approach into an expression-based one?
Here’s my current function that works with DataFrames:
from typing import Callable, Sequence
import numpy as np
import polars as pl
from numba import guvectorize

@guvectorize(['(float64[:], int64, float64[:])'], '(n),()->(n)')
def rolling_func(input_array, window_size, out):
    """Example for a custom rolling function with a specified window size."""
    n = len(input_array)
    for i in range(n):
        start = max(i - window_size + 1, 0)
        out[i] = np.mean(input_array[start:i+1])


def apply_rolling_gathered_agg(
        df,
        func: Callable,
        window_size: int,
        *func_args,
        group_col: str | list[str] | None = None,
        value_col: str | None = None,
        result_col: str = 'result',
        every_nth: int = 1,
        window_buffer: int = 0,
        return_dtype: pl.DataType = pl.Float64) -> pl.DataFrame:
    """
    Apply a custom rolling aggregation function to a DataFrame, with grouping and every nth value selection.

    This function performs a rolling aggregation on a specified value column in a Polars DataFrame. It allows
    grouping by one or more columns, gathering every nth value, and applying a custom aggregation function
    (e.g., `rolling_func`) with a specified window size and optional buffer.

    Args:
        df (pl.DataFrame): The DataFrame to operate on.
        func (Callable): The aggregation function to apply to each rolling window.
        window_size (int): The size of the window over which to apply the aggregation function.
        *func_args: Additional arguments to pass to the custom function.
        group_col (str | list[str] | None, optional): The column(s) to group by. If `None`, the first column is used.
        value_col (str | None, optional): The column to apply the rolling function to. If `None`, the last column is used.
        result_col (str, optional): The name of the result column in the output DataFrame. Default is 'result'.
        every_nth (int, optional): The step size for gathering values within each group. Default is 1.
        window_buffer (int, optional): A buffer to add around the rolling window, extending the window on both ends. Default is 0.
        return_dtype (pl.DataType, optional): The desired data type for the result column. Default is `pl.Float64`.

    Returns:
        pl.DataFrame: A DataFrame containing the results of the rolling aggregation, with one row per group.


    Example:
        # Create a sample DataFrame with two groups 'A' and 'B', and values from 0 to 99
        df = pl.DataFrame({
            'group': np.repeat(['A', 'B'], 100),  # Repeat 'A' and 'B' for each group
            'value': np.tile(np.arange(100), 2)   # Tile the values 0 to 99 for each group
        })
        func_args = []
        res = apply_rolling_gathered_agg(
            df,
            func=rolling_func,
            window_size=3,
            *func_args,
            group_col='group',
            value_col='value',
            every_nth=10,
            window_buffer=0,
            return_dtype=pl.Float64,
        )
        print(res)
        res_pd = res.to_pandas()
    """
    # Handle cases where group_col or value_col might not be passed
    cols = df.columns
    group_col = group_col or cols[0]
    value_col = value_col or cols[-1]

    # If group_col is a list, ensure it is processed correctly
    if isinstance(group_col, list):
        group_by = group_col
    else:
        group_by = [group_col]

    # Temporary index column for rolling aggregation
    index_col = '_index'

    # Calculate the total window size
    total_window = every_nth * (window_size + window_buffer)
    period = f'{total_window}i'

    # Apply rolling aggregation
    result = (
        df
        .with_row_index(name=index_col)
        .rolling(index_column=index_col, period=period, group_by=group_by)
        .agg(
            pl.all().last(),  # pass the last element of all present columns
            pl.col(value_col)
            .reverse().gather_every(every_nth).reverse()
            .map_batches(lambda batch: func(batch, window_size, *func_args), return_dtype=return_dtype)
            .last().alias(result_col))  # This is the desired expression
        .drop(index_col)
    )
    return result

I want to convert this function into an expression-based function, similar to:
def expr_apply_rolling_gathered_agg(
        group_expr: pl.Expr | Sequence[pl.Expr],  # Single or list of group column expressions
        value_expr: pl.Expr,  # Expression for the value column (series/column)
        func: Callable,       # The rolling aggregation function
        window_size: int,     # Size of the rolling window
        *func_args,           # Additional arguments for the rolling function
        every_nth: int = 1,   # Step size for gathering values
        window_buffer: int = 0,  # Buffer size around the window
        return_dtype: pl.DataType = pl.Float64  # Output data type
) -> pl.Expr:
    pass

EDIT: Is rolling_map suitable as replacement for rolling & map_batches? rolling_map seems to expect a Custom aggregation function. It returns the first result for each rolling window if the function is not an aggregation like in this case:
series = pl.Series(pl.arange(10, eager=True)).rolling_map(lambda x: x+1, window_size=3)
print(series.to_list())
[None, None, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]


Is map_batches inside rolling agg basically the same as a .rolling_map()?

I'm unsure if rolling_map can be used in this context. The combination of rolling and map_batches is being used to create equal or larger lookback windows (defined by window_buffer), which are then passed to a specialized rolling function (written with Numba). This function operates within the defined window during a grouping operation.
Do you see a way to stitch these processes together in an expression-based manner (i.e., group -> roll -> gather -> map)?

It's hard to tell but it looks to be similar to what .rolling_map(lambda x: func(x.gather_every()), total_window).over(group) would achieve? To do it efficiently though, you'd probably need to replace numba with a Rust plugin: https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/plugins/your-first-polars-plugin/ - so that you can use it directly in .agg() without needing to execute any UDFs.

It would be interesting to see the difference between a Rust plugin and the Numba UDF. Nevertheless, your proposal is pretty awesome. I get the same expression based result using "value_expr.rolling_map(lambda x: func(x.gather_every(every_nth, offset=every_nth-1), window_size, *func_args).last(), total_window).over(group_expr)". Thank you very much!!!

As it stands, it's basically doing for group in rolling_groups: func(group) - https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/expressions/aggregation/#do-not-kill-parallelization - Even though func is "fast" (numba), you have the cost of the sequential nature due to executing external UDFs.

In Polars, is there a way to bypass the GIL in a grouping operation if the applied function is a generalized ufunc? What do you think? The execution of the function itself will be fast https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/expressions/user-defined-python-functions/#fast-operations-with-user-defined-functions

A problem might be that mapping a custom function using i.e. map_batches requires workarounds like lambda or functools.partial to pass additional arguments to the custom function.

@jqurious I'm not sure anymore that rolling_map is suitable. It seems to return different results compared to rolling and map_batches (see the edit above). A better solution might be to generate a NumPy sliding window view and apply the gufunc row-wise. You would avoid slowish Python loops.
